# How to change which array I want to modify in a loop without having to type each of them

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

So I want to change many arrays in a similar way but I'm wondering if instead of doing something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if(i==0)
                {
                    attack1[0] = attacks[i];
                    attack1[1] = Convert.ToString(atdmg[i]);
                    attack1[2] = ateffect[i];
                    attack1[3] = Convert.ToString(ataccur[i]);
                    attack1[4] = Convert.ToString(atmul[i]);
                }
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    attack2[0] = attacks[i];
                    attack2[1] = Convert.ToString(atdmg[i]);
                    attack2[2] = ateffect[i];
                    attack2[3] = Convert.ToString(ataccur[i]);
                    attack2[4] = Convert.ToString(atmul[i]);
                }
                if (i == 2)
                {
                    attack3[0] = attacks[i];
                    attack3[1] = Convert.ToString(atdmg[i]);
                    attack3[2] = ateffect[i];
                    attack3[3] = Convert.ToString(ataccur[i]);
                    attack3[4] = Convert.ToString(atmul[i]);
                }
                if (i == 3)
                {
                    attack4[0] = attacks[i];
                    attack4[1] = Convert.ToString(atdmg[i]);
                    attack4[2] = ateffect[i];
                    attack4[3] = Convert.ToString(ataccur[i]);
                    attack4[4] = Convert.ToString(atmul[i]);
                }

            }
```

I could do something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                    attacki[0] = attacks[i];
                    attacki[1] = Convert.ToString(atdmg[i]);
                    attacki[2] = ateffect[i];
                    attacki[3] = Convert.ToString(ataccur[i]);
                    attacki[4] = Convert.ToString(atmul[i]);
            }
```

so that I don't have to type each one. The point of the code is to put information from other arrays into other arrays to simplify printing information in the long run

Comment: I don’t think you need a loop really, you can directly set

Comment: Well I don't need a loop for the way I did it but it would help if I can change the array I want to modify with the loop, unless another tool can do that

Comment: Consider making a 2d array `String[,] attacks = new String[4, 5];` and storing your data in that instead of `attack1`, `attack2`, etc.

Comment: Right! I still haven't seen how to do 2d arrays but they would make sense in this case

Comment: We don't know any of the types involved or what anything is expected to represent. I *suspect* you should create a new type to compose the five values you've got here, which will simplify everything a lot, but you haven't presented anywhere like enough information for us to tell, really.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think that you really need a loop here. You can simply write like this.

```
attack1[0] = attacks[0];
attack1[1] = Convert.ToString(atdmg[0]);
attack1[2] = ateffect[0];
attack1[3] = Convert.ToString(ataccur[0]);
attack1[4] = Convert.ToString(atmul[0]);
```

And similarly for other items.

You can also wrap these lines in a method and call the method based by passing the respective attack object.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot change a variable's name like

> attacki

A suggestion could be creating a function to do the job inside the loop.
This function could take the array, i, and the other necessary data.

```
for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)
{
   if(i==0)     
     doSomething(attack1, i, ...)
   else if(i==1)
      ...
}
```

and then

```
public void doSomething(array, no, ...)
{
   do your stuff here
}
```

EDIT: You don't really need a loop either anyway. You can just do:

```
doSomething(attack1, 0, ...)
doSomething(attack2, 1, ...)
doSomething(attack3, 2, ...)
doSomething(attack4, 3, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should package your attack{i} Arrays into a list. Then you could use a foreach loop to update all of them achieving something similar to what you asked for. The code would look something like this:

```
            // Your arrays goes in this
            var attackList = new List<string[]>();
            int index = 0;
            foreach (var attack in attackList)
            {
                attack[0] = attacks[index];
                attack[1] = Convert.ToString(atdmg[index]);
                attack[2] = ateffect[index];
                attack[3] = Convert.ToString(ataccur[index]);
                attack[4] = Convert.ToString(atmul[index);
                index++;
            }
```

Comment: I tried putting in my code but when I try to put the info in the console it just returns blank, is there something else I should do?